# Can I use AgensGraph with PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, graph-databases, agens-graph

I'm developing the application about LBS with PostGIS.
I figured out the graph database has also shortest path algorithm.
Then I found the AgensGraph (GDB).
It looks possible because AgensGraph incubates the PostgreSQL. But when I install PostGIS additionally, I don't know what happens.
So can I use Lat/Long data and advanced shortest path algorithm in AgensGraph?

Comment: Did you try `create extension postgis` the way you did it in Postgres?

Comment: I did. I think I can use the PostGIS functions as usual on AgensGraph. But my question is, is there any correlational interface between AgensGraph and PostGIS?